# Get instance of parent of a class in constructor of class

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypejs

```
var Shape = Class.create(new Element("div", {
    "class": "shape"
}), {
    //constructor of Shape
    initialize: function () {

    }
})
```

Shape class inherit from an *instance* of Element, all what I want to get to know is, how can I refer to this *instance* in constructor of Shape if I can?

Comment: You can't really inherit from an instance. Why would you do that?

Comment: @dfsq I do not understand your wondering, "old" (it is updated 5 months ago) things can be good.

Comment: @Bergi: Can't inherit from an instance? Do you mean with PrototypeJS's inheritance? Standard prototypal inheritance is *based* on inheriting from instances.

Comment: @user1689607: Yeah, sure. Although the standard JS inheritance uses prototype objects that are "instances" of `Object`, as they're created via `Object.create` and not with `new` - there was no constructor function applied on them. And so, also Prototype's `Class.create` seems to expect a [constructor] function as the first argument, not an "instance".

Comment: @user1689607 sure but it doesn't really make sense here. I mean all the instances of shape share the same dom element... why would anyone want to do that. For that matter, why would you even want to inherit dom methods which are all based on native magic, they cannot possibly be useful for userland objects.

Comment: @Esailija: Yeah, I'm not sure what the use case would be for using a DOM element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/r585d/

Use this to refer to the `Element` instance inside `Shape` constructor:

`this.constructor.prototype`

Alternatively, you could do this (Since it doesn't make sense for a shape to inherit from element):

```
var Shape = (function() {
    var elem = new Element("div", {
        "class": "shape"
    });
    return Class.create({
        initialize: function() {
            //refer to elem here    
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: If it does, then why does `.nodeName` return `undefined`?

Comment: @user1689607 no it doesn't (return `undefined`), try the jsfiddle. Also see http://jsfiddle.net/r585d/1/

Comment: ...yep, tried your new fiddle too. I get `undefined undefined`. ...Firefox 16 on Linux

Comment: @user1689607 ah I see. I am using chrome. Switch to some other library while you still can.

Comment: Yep, works in Chrome. Strange. Using Prototype 1.6.1 works with Firefox.

Comment: How is it even possible, it's not like the browser differ that much in their core ecmascript implementation.. I can understand DOM.

Comment: As you can see instance of Element is an insertable object. The reason why I would like reach it, is I want to insert it to somewhere.

$$("selector").insert(this.constructor.prototype) do not work.

Comment: @SándorRakonczai try the new code (which doesn't use inheritance)